# What is the MacBook Pro's infrared port used for?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I know my macbook has an infrared port, but I don't know what it's used for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most typically, it is used for the [Apple Remote](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC377LL/A), which can control iTunes, QuickTime and various other built in software. Additionally, 3rd party software (see [Sofa Remote](http://www.caseapps.com/sofacontrol/) and [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/)) also makes use of the device and can tie in much more functionality.

In the past (prior to Lion), the Apple Remote was an excellent companion to [Front Row](http://www.macworld.com/article/161284/2011/07/farewell_frontrow.html), a media manager that some call the predecessor to the Apple TV interface.